# batteryStatus not displaying correctly

Tags: android, batterylevel

I am trying to display on an app if a phone is being charged by a plug, a usb cable or not charging at all. I am using the code below, it will display "charging via usb cable" if I am using a usb cable and it displays "not charging" if the phone battery is full or not charging. But when I am charging the phone via a plug then it will show "charging via usb cable". I am using a normal ac plug charger and not an ac plug charger where you can stick in a usb cable (if that matters). Why does this happen?

```
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, filter);

        int chargeState = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

        if(chargeState == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB)
        {
            chargingBy = "charging via usb cable";
        }
        else if (chargeState == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC)
        {
            chargingBy = "charging via plug";
        }
        else
        {
            chargingBy = "not charging";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different types of USB ports:

1. The standard port.
2. A charging downstream port.
3. A dedicated charging port.

> The first two can be found on your computer and the third kind applies
>   to “dumb” wall chargers

What phone model are you testing on?

---

`EXTRA_STATUS` Is not used to know how the device is being charget

use `EXTRA_PLUGGED` instead

Comment: That works now thanks :) So the extra_status is used to know if the battery is being charged and the extra_plugged is used to know how the battery is being charger?

Comment: That's great, Exactly :)